# How to find couples of numbers with the same sum from 1 to n and from n+1 to m

Tags: c

So, I have to make a work for college and it consists in creating an algorithm.

The algorithm must find couples of numbers which satisfy a certain condition, which is: the sum from `1` to `n` (exlusive) results the same as the sum from `n+1` to `m` (inclusive).

At the final, the algorithm must give at least 15 couples.

The first couple is `6` and `8`, because from `1` to `n` (exclusive) (6) is `1+2+3+4+5` = `15` and from `n+1` to `m` is `8+7` = `15`.

The algorithm I created is the following one:

```
int main() {
    int count = 0;
    unsigned int before = 0;
    unsigned int after = 0;
    unsigned int n = 1;
    unsigned int m = 0;
    do {
        before += n - 1;
        after = n + 1;
        for (m = after + 1; after < before; m++) {
            after += m;
        }
        if (before == after) {
            printf("%d\t%d\n", n, (m - 1));
            count++;
        }
        n++;
    } while (count < 15);
}
```

This is actually OK, but some of the output are not correct, and its also crap, in terms of complexity, and since I am studying Complexity of Algorithms, it would be good to find some algorithm better than this one.

I also tried doing it in Java, but using int is not good for this problem and using long, it takes hours and hours to compute.

The numbers I have found so far:

```
6 and 8  
35 and 49  
204 and 288   
1189 and 1681  
6930 and 9800  
40391 and 57121
```

The following ones may be incorrect:

```
100469 and 107694  
115619 and 134705  
121501 and 144689  
740802 and 745928  
1250970 and 1251592  
2096128 and 2097152  
2100223 and 2101246  
4196352 and 8388608  
18912301 and 18912497
```

Comment: Err... where is `i` defined for `after += i;`? Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: Why are you using brute-force. Why dont you use the formula n*(n+1)/2. if you want for 5-10, you can do (10*11/2) - (5*6/2)

Comment: Please show us the incorrect results it gives you.

Comment: @WeatherVane just edited the code, it was my mistake to put the i, it was m instead

Comment: Consider that `sum_before(n) = n*(n-1)/2` and `sum_after(n,m) = sum_before(m+1) - sum_before(n+1)`. Try solving for m in terms of n, and then writing code to see if that calculated m is an integer for a given n.

Comment: it would give sum of 6,7,8,9,10.

Comment: Or try solving for `n` in terms of `m`, and looping through possible values of `m` and for ones that give you an integer `n`, print those `m`s and `n`s

Comment: I tried using those ideas, problem is: I don't know when to stop the counting after n, that's why I use the looping with the `before == after` condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial brute force program as posted above generates plenty of data for you to analyze.  The people in the question's comments recommended the "sum of an arithmetic series" formula instead of your repeated addition, but the fact is that it still would run slow.  It's surely an improvement, but it's still not good enough if you want something usable.

Believe it or not, there are some patterns to the values of `n` and `m`, which will require some math to explain.  I'll be using the functions `n(i)`, `m(i)`, and `d(i) = m(i) - n(i)` to represent the values of `n`, `m`, and the difference between them, respectively, during iteration `i`.

You found the first six couples:

```
 i   n(i)   m(i)   d(i)
== ====== ====== ======
 1      6      8      2
 2     35     49     14
 3    204    288     84
 4   1189   1681    492
 5   6930   9800   2870
 6  40391  57121  16730
```

Notice that `6+8 = 14`, `35+49 = 84`, `204+288 = 492`, etc.  It so happens that, in the general case, `d(i+1) = m(i) + n(i)` (e.g. `d(2) = m(1) + n(1) = 6 + 8 = 14`).

So now we know the following:

```
  d(7)
= n(6) + m(6)
= 40391 + 57121
= 97512

# m(i) = n(i) + d(i)
m(7) = n(7) + 97512
```

Another way of looking at it since `m(i) = n(i) + d(i)` is `d(i+1) = d(i) + 2n(i)`:

```
  d(7)
= n(6) + d(6) + n(6)
= d(6) + 2n(6)
= 16730 + 2(40391)
= 97512
```

`d(i)` also happens to be useful for computing `n(i+1)`:

```
n(i+1) = 2d(i+1) + n(i) + 1

n(7) = 2d(7) + n(6) + 1
    = 2(97512) + 40391 + 1
    = 235416
```

From there, it's easy to determine things:

```
 i   n(i)   m(i)   d(i)
== ====== ====== ======
1       6      2      8
2      35     14     49
3     204     84    288
4    1189    492   1681
5    6930   2870   9800
6   40391  16370  57121
7  235416 332928  97512
```

But what about a starting condition?  We need a way to find `6` in the first place, and that starting case can be computed by working backward and using substitution:

```
n(1) = 2d(1) + n(0) + 1
   6 = 2(2) + n(0) + 1
   5 = 4 + n(0)
   1 = n(0)

d(1) = d(0) + 2n(0)
   2 = d(0) + 2(1)
   2 = d(0) + 2
   0 = d(0)

m(0) = n(0) + d(0)
     = 1 + 0
     = 1
```

Note that `n(0) = m(0)` (`1 = 1`), but it is not a couple.  For a pair of numbers to be a couple, the numbers must not be the same.

All that's left is to compute the sum.  Since the integers from 1 to n-1 (i.e. 1 to n, excluding n) form an arithmetic series and the series starts at 1, you can use the formula

```
       n(n - 1)
S(n) = --------
          2
```

Below is a program that uses all of this information.  You'll notice I'm using a multiplication function `mul` in place of the multiplication operator.  The function's result is used to end the loop prematurely when an unsigned overflow (i.e. wraparound) is encountered.  There are probably better ways to detect the wraparound behavior, and the algorithm could be better designed, but it works.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned long long uval_t;

/*
 * Uses a version of the "FOIL method" to multiply two numbers.
 * If overflow occurs, 0 is returned, and errno is ERANGE.
 * Otherwise, no overflow occurs, and the product m*n is returned.
 */
uval_t mul(uval_t m, uval_t n)
{
/*
 * Shift amount is half the number of bits in uval_t.
 * This allows us to work with the upper and lower halves.
 * If the upper half of F is not zero, overflow occurs and zero is returned.
 * If the upper half of (O+I << half_shift) + L is not zero,
 * overflow occurs and zero is returned.
 * Otherwise, the returned value is the mathematically accurate result of m*n.
 */
#define half_shift ((sizeof (uval_t) * CHAR_BIT) >> 1)
#define rsh(v) ((v) >> half_shift)
#define lsh(v) ((v) << half_shift)
    uval_t a[2], b[2];
    uval_t f, o, i, l;

    a[0] = rsh(m);
    a[1] = m & ~lsh(a[0]);
    b[0] = rsh(n);
    b[1] = n & ~lsh(b[0]);

    f = a[0] * b[0];
    if (f != 0)
    {
        errno = ERANGE;
        return 0;
    }

    o = a[0] * b[1];
    i = a[1] * b[0];
    l = a[1] * b[1];

    if (rsh(o+i + rsh(l)) != 0)
    {
        errno = ERANGE;
        return 0;
    }

    return lsh(o+i) + l;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    uval_t n = 1, d = 0;
    uval_t sum = 0;
#define MAX 15

    for (i = 1; i <= MAX; i++)
    {
        d += n * 2;
        n += d * 2 + 1;
        sum = mul(n, n - 1) / 2;
        if (sum == 0)
            break;
        printf("%2d\t%20llu\t%20llu\t%20llu\n", i, n, n+d, sum);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This yields 12 lines of output, the last being this one:

```
12            1583407981              2239277041     1253590416355544190
```

Of course, if you don't care about the sums, then you can just avoid computing them entirely, and you can find all 15 couples just fine without even needing to check for overflow of a 64-bit type.

To go further with the sums, you have a few options, in order of most to least recommended:

- use a "bignum" library such as [GNU MP](https://gmplib.org/), which is similar to Java's `java.math.BigInteger` class and which has its own `printf`-like function for displaying values; if you're on Linux, it may already be available
- use your compiler's 128-bit type, assuming it has one available, and create your own printing function for it if necessary
- create your own "big integer" type and the associated necessary addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, etc. printing functions for it; a way that allows for easy printing is that it could just be two `unsigned long long` values glued together with one representing the lower 19 decimal digits (i.e. the max value for it would be 999 9999 9999 9999 9999), and the other representing the upper 19 digits for a total of 38 digits, which is 10<sup>38</sup>-1 or 127 bits

The fact that the full 15 sums required don't fit in 64 bits, however, makes me concerned that the question was perhaps worded badly and wanted something different from what you wrote.

*Edit*

To prove this works, we must first establish some rules:

- For any values `n` and `m`, `0 ≤ n < m` must be true, meaning `n == m` is forbidden (else we don't have a couple, a.k.a. "ordered pair").
- `n` and `m` must both be integers.

With that out of the way, consider an algorithm for computing the sum of an arithmetic series starting at `a` and ending at, and including, `b` with a difference of +1 between each successive term:

```
          (b - a + 1)(b + a)
S(a, b) = ------------------
                  2

          b² - a² + b + a
        = ---------------
                2

          b(1 + b) + a(1 - a)
        = -------------------
                   2
```

If such a series begins at `a=1`, you can derive a simpler formula:

```
        b(b + 1)
 S(b) = --------
           2
```

Applying this to your problem, you want to know how to find values such that the following is true:

```
 S(n-1) = S(n+1, m)
```

After applying the arguments, the result looks like this:

```
  (n-1)n   m(1 + m) + (n+1)[1 - (n+1)]
  ------ = ---------------------------
     2                2

  (n-1)n = m(1 + m) + (n+1)(1 - n - 1)

  n² - n = m² + m + (n+1)(-n)

  n² - n = m² + m - n² - n

 2n²     = m² + m
```

While not important for my purposes, it's perhaps worth noting that `m² + m` can be rewritten as `m(m+1)`, and the `2n²` signifies that one or both of `m` and `m+1` must be divisible by 2.  In addition, one must be a perfect square while the other must be twice a perfect square due to the requirement that at least one expression must be divisible by 2.  In other words, `2n² = m(m+1) = 2x²y²`.  You can find another equally valid solution using `x` and `y` to generate the values of `n` and `m`, but I won't demonstrate that here.

Given the equations for `n(i+1)`, `m(i+1)`, and `d(i+1)`:

```
  d(i+1) = d(i) + 2n(i)
         = m(i) + n(i)

  n(i+1) = 2d(i+1) + n(i) + 1
         = 2m(i) + 3n(i) + 1

  m(i+1) = d(i+1) + n(i+1)
         = 3m(i) + 4n(i) + 1
```

And the starting conditions:

```
n(0) = 1
d(0) = 0
m(0) = 1
```

We can determine whether they actually work by substituting `i+2` in place of `i` in all cases and finding whether we end up with the same equation.  Assuming `f(n(i)) = 2n²(i)` and `g(m(i)) = m(i) ⋅ (m(i) + 1)`, the equation `f(n(i+2)) = g(m(i+2))` reduces to `f(n(i)) = g(m(i))`, proving the equations work for any couple:

```
  f(n(i+2))
= g(m(i+2))

  f(2m(i+1) + 3n(i+1) + 1)
= g((3m(i+1) + 4n(i+1) + 1))

  2 ⋅ (12m(i) + 17n(i) + 6)²
=     (17m(i) + 24n(i) + 8) ⋅ (17m(i) + 24n(i) + 8 + 1)

  2 ⋅ (144m²(i) + 408m(i)⋅n(i) + 144m(i) + 289n²(i) + 204n(i) + 36)
=      289m²(i) + 816m(i)⋅n(i) + 289m(i) + 576n²(i) + 408n(i) + 72

       288m²(i) + 816m(i)⋅n(i) + 288m(i) + 578n²(i) + 408n(i) + 72
=      289m²(i) + 816m(i)⋅n(i) + 289m(i) + 576n²(i) + 408n(i) + 72

  2n²(i)
= m²(i) + m(i)

  f(n(i))
= g(m(i))
```

If you're lost toward the end, I simply subtracted `288m²(i) + 816m(i)⋅n(i) + 288m(i) + 576n²(i) + 408n(i) + 72` from both sides of the equation, yielding `2n²(i) = m²(i) + m(i)`.

Comment: Your observation is very interesting and this algorithm does produce 15 pairs immediately. This seems to suffice for the OP's problem as stated: *The algorithm must find couples of numbers which satisfy a certain condition...* it does not say it must find the first 15 pairs that satisfy this condition. You did not give a mathematical proof for your recurrence, nor that it generates all possible pairs. Is is true?

Comment: Quite an extensive answer :)

Answer (score 7):

Your results are incorrect beyond the first 6: the range of type `unsigned int` is insufficient to store the sums. You should use type `unsigned long long` for `before` and `after`.

Furthermore, your algorithm becomes very slow for large values because you recompute `after` from scratch for each new value of `before`, with a time complexity of **O(N<sup>2</sup>)**. You can keep 2 running sums in parallel and reduce the complexity to quasi-linear.

Last but not least, there are only 12 solutions below `UINT32_MAX`, so type `unsigned long long`, which is guaranteed to have at least 64 value bits is required for `n` and `m` as well. To avoid incorrect results, overflow should be tested when updating `after`.

Further tests show that the sums `after` and `before` exceed 64 bits for values of `m` around `8589934591`. A solution is to subtract 2<sup>62</sup> from both `before` and `after` when they reach 2<sup>63</sup>. With this modification, the program can keep searching for larger values of `n` and `m` much beyond 32-bits.

Here is an improved version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int count = 0;
    unsigned long long n = 1;
    unsigned long long m = 2;
    unsigned long long before = 0;
    unsigned long long after = 2;

    for (;;) {
        if (before < after) {
            before += n;
            n++;
            after -= n;
        } else {
            m++;
            /* reduce values to prevent overflow */
            if (after > 0x8000000000000000) {
                after -= 0x4000000000000000;
                before -= 0x4000000000000000;
            }
            after += m;
            while (before > after) {
                after += n;
                n--;
                before -= n;
            }
        }
        if (before == after) {
            printf("%llu\t%llu\n", n, m);
            count++;
            if (count == 15)
                break;
        }
    }
    printf("%d solutions up to %llu\n", count, m);
    return 0;
}
```

Output (running time 30 minutes):

```
6       8
35      49
204     288
1189    1681
6930    9800
40391   57121
235416  332928
1372105 1940449
7997214 11309768
46611179        65918161
271669860       384199200
1583407981      2239277041
9228778026      13051463048
53789260175     76069501249
313506783024    443365544448
15 solutions up to 443365544448
```

Comment: _the sum from 1 to n(**exlusive**) results the same as the sum from n+1 to m(**inclusive**)_. `n` should not be included in the original calculation, so for n=6, it's 1+2+3+4+5, n=3 is 1+2, etc.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune: I updated the code and improved the answer. Thank you for catching the problem